# Azure Service Bus equivalent?

Tags: azure, cloud, servicebus

I've been studying Azure's Service Bus and was wondering... Are there any equivalent services provided by other cloud vendors such as AWS, Rackspace or App Engine?

I read in a blog post that it would be possible to install ESB solutions such as Apache ServiceMix into IaaS providers' instances. Yet, I am not sure if they offer the same kind of functionality provided by Azure.

Also, is there any cloud equivalent of Azure's Access Control service for federated authentication?

I'm still trying to figure out these offers and compare them, but I am not sure if what I'm doing is like comparing apples to oranges.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: This almost sounds like a business opportunity...

Answer (score 10):

Others:

- Kafka
- Redis pub/sub
- RabbitMQ
- ActiveMQ
- WebSphereMQ
- (to some extent) ZeroMQ
- STOMP
- XMPP
- etc ...

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com)

I've been watching this service grow over the last few months and have been impressed with their support and changes according to customer feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon Simple Queue Service

http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

Comment: From my point of view Amazon SQS equates to Azure Storage Queue while an alternative to Azure Service Bus can be achieved combining Amazon SQS to Amazon SNS Topic.
With no direct experience on Amazon I cannot affirm/deny there is feature parity considering latest improvement to Azure Service Bus like partitioned entities http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/10/29/partitioned-service-bus-queues-and-topics.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Interesting that there is no answer to this question after 2 weeks. I do not know of any equivalent.

Many of the cloud service providers, provide Infrastructure as a Service (OS instances), rather than a platform like Azure. It is up to you what you place on those instances.

A good place to start for comparing cloud offerings is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing

Answer (score 2):

The landscape has changed since this question was asked. Now there is the [**Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP 1.0)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol), which intends to standardize messaging.

[Azure Service Bus has adopted the protocol](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-amqp-overview/), and you could also spin up IaaS instances of [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com) at other cloud providers.

Sounds to me the way to go (I'm also investigating this kind of setup), although I have no personal experience. Comments would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a XMPP application server.  Ejabberd is popular and includes a Service bus module (mod_pubsub).

Setup instructions:
http://blog.kenweiner.com/2008/05/ejabberd-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-ami.html

mod_pubsub info:
http://www.ejabberd.im/mod_pubsub-usage

There may be also be pre-build images available.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BeeSphere Cloud Service Bus](http://www.beesphere.net)

Answer (score 0):

[Thinktecture.IdentityServer](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2) is ACS equivalent for federated authentication

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure iron.io's offerings can be fanagled into your use case with the mix other distributed pieces like kinesis, kafka, samza.